# R' Meir of Rotenburg responsum cited by Mahari Bruna

Tags: sources-mekorot, beit-din-court, responsa

At the end of Mahari Bruna responsum 111 ([שו"ת מהר"י מברונא סימן קיא](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1841&pgnum=82)) he refers to a responsum by R' Meir of Rotenburg in which it was held that anyone could demand, on pain of cherem, a copy of any document pertaining to them from the files of another person. 
Can anyone help me find the R' Meir responsum he’s citing?

Comment: the closest I could find is this: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Teshuvot_Maharam%2C_Prague_Edition.641.3?vhe=Teshuvot_Maharam_bar_Barukh,_Budapest,_1895&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: I believe it’s [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1137&st=&pgnum=311) responsum (Berlin, II 48) where Maharam states that, in order to obtain information regarding a certain matter (in that case, the reason for a wife’s rebelliousness), a community may pronounce a ban on anybody in possession of information and does not come forward.